# Qt5 to Qt4 UI File Compatibility

Tags: c++, qt, backwards-compatibility

Are Qt5 generated UI/form files backwards compatible with Qt4? As in, can I take the source, headers, and UI files and recompile with Qt4 without issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files *generated* by `uic` in Qt 5 will have `#include <QtWidgets/QFoo>`, which of course doesn't work in Qt 4.

Or are you talking about `.ui` files generated by Qt Designer / Creator? Those will instead work without changes (modulo using Qt 5-only or Qt 4-only classes, of course).

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the .ui files, the xml files that display a form when opened in QtCreator. So are you telling me that those are backwards-compatable?

Comment: I'm quite sure it is, but nothing can guarantee that it will stay that way forever, i.e. the .ui format won't change in a non-backwards compatible way some time in Qt 5. After all, people are more interested in porting code from Qt 4 to 5, not vice-versa :-)

Comment: How about `.ui` files generated by Qt Designer 4? Will those work with `Qt5 uic`?